# Django: Related model 'users.UserProfile' cannot be resolved

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, django-1.10

I tried running makemigrations and after migrate and I am constantly getting this error:

```
ValueError: Related model 'users.UserProfile' cannot be resolved
```

What I was trying to do is Link a **UserProfile** model to Django's own **User** Model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    website = models.URLField(blank=True)
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
```

The "**Contests**" model (as you can see in my installed apps below) uses the User Model as well without any errors.

My **Installed apps** look like this :

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'users',
    'social.apps.django_app.default',
    'crispy_forms',
    'pages',
    'contests',
]
```

My migration file **0001_initial.py** is the following:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Generated by Django 1.10.3 on 2016-12-30 15:45
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.conf import settings
from django.db import migrations, models
import django.db.models.deletion


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
        migrations.swappable_dependency(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='UserProfile',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('website', models.URLField(blank=True)),
                ('bio', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=250)),
                ('full_name', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=250)),
                ('user', models.OneToOneField(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)),
            ],
        ),
    ]
```

Other notes:

1. I use multiple settings files but my installed apps are all in my base setting file so this should not be the issue.
2. I am using Python Social Auth to create a Pipeline and create the UserProfile. (But this should not have any effect on the creation of the model in the database)
3. I even dropped the database and recreated it but I still get the same error.

Thanks in advance!!! :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I have deleted all migration files from other apps and run makemigrations and migrate again.

Everything Works now.

Answer (score 6):

Try running migrations one by one for every model.

This way you can debug the `app` you are facing problem with

```
python manage.py migrate appmname
```

Maybe running migrations one by one may help

Comment: Looked for a solution for this for weeks, this is perfect, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I experienced a similar issue where i created a custom user model (as written in the documentation before the first migrate).

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    pass

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'account.user'
```

When trying to migrate i ran into "ValueError: Related model 'account.user' cannot be resolved".

It got resolved after i first generated the migration for the new custom user model.

Paul